# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in

Tags: php

Help me spot the error please. I have declared the function string but PHP is not seeing it in the included file. Here is part of the code;

```
$startpage = function () { return '<div class="mi-page">'; };
    $pagebreak = function () { return '<div class="break" style="page-break-after: always;"></div>'; };
    $endpage = function () { return '</div>'; };
```

Somewhere in the file below this code. I have;

```
require (CURRENT_TEMPLATE.'/template.php');
```

It is funny because because $pagebreak() works but not $startpage() and $endpage()

I have just added the $startpage() and $endpage() functions today but results in;

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in...

The three variable functions are called in the included file using require.

Hope you will spot the error me. Thanks.

************Further details*******************
I literally just call the variable functions in the template.php file. At the very top of the template.php file I have;

```
$html.= $startpage();
```

Half way the file I have;

```
foreach ($questions() as $question){
$html.= '<div style="overflow:hidden;">';
if ($i==0){$image = image(0); $html.= '<div class="image1">'.$image.'</div>';}
$html.= $question;
$html.= '</div>';

$html .= $pagebreak();
$i++;
}
```

And lastly;

```
$html.= $endpage();
```

There is not alot of code in this file which would cause any problems.

I get the error:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home4/../slim/template.php on line 2

Comment: We cannot help without seeing the contents of `template.php`. Variable functions seem an odd choice, especially since the functions themselves are extremely static.

Comment: What is the exact error message? What line does it point to? What are the values of the variables on that line? Likely one of your variables is not actually a function when you try to call it, but has been overwritten with something else.

Comment: Hi, I have added areas of the file where the variables are called. The file is being included in a class method. The variables have been declared in a method. This is an imitation of wordpress: if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

Comment: You have added multiple blocks of code, which one specifically does the error point to? And what does `var_dump($yourFunctionVar)` (replace with variable that causes the error) show exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Problem solved. Two methods containing the same block of code. Forgot to create a single function to avoid duplicates. I have been editing the wrong method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in foreach, $questions() is not a function, check it

Comment: $questions() is a function otherwise I would have got an error for it. It is one of the other variables that I have declared as functions. Only today when I added $startpage() and $endpage() PHP is not seeing them.

Comment: can show me all script? for try to help better to you